# Connect HYPER-V to Physical on KMloop back Test

Tags: hyper-v

I am sorry if this is too simple but here I go.

I have created a hyper V simple environment, in which I want to use 3 Vms connected to physical with a KM loopback adapter.

I used this setup before for the VM ware it worked.. i assigned the same range IP on this loopback adapter and it pings to all the vms.

[Virtual Switch to External with allow management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMBxx.png)

[KM loopback assigned the IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA1Fr.png)